# Reminders & Alarms don't go off in Driving Mode

Tags: 8.1, driving-mode

Ever since I updated to 8.1, I've noticed that Reminders and Alarms don't go off while in Driving Mode. This would seem to be a rather critical failure, as it's common for me to need certain alerts while I'm driving.

A prime example of the need for this would be a daily teleconference that I call into on the way to work. Another one would be just about any "remind me to get X when I'm near the store" type reminder.

These alerts don't happen while in Driving Mode, but I do see them pop up when I check my phone after I've gotten out of the car. But by then, I've already missed the teleconference or gotten home without the milk.

Is there a way to change this, without disabling Driving Mode?

Answer (score 3):

This is the purpose of driving mode - to not distract you whilst you're driving. If you don't want his behaviour, don't use driving mode.

To quote the initial settings page:

> Driving Mode turns off all notifications except texts and phone calls when you're driving. You can also turn calls off completely or set Driving Mode to text an automatic reply. To get started, you'll need a Bluetooth device.

(or if you're still using 8.0):

> Driving Mode turns off all notifications except texts and phone calls when you're driving. You can also turn calls off completely or set Driving Mode to text an automatic reply (We'll never ignore emergency calls and alerts.)

Comment: IIRC, it didn't work this way before the 8.1 update. Driving Mode has options to enable/disable texts & calls, but I don't see such choice available for other alerts.

Comment: I've added the wording from the setup for both 8.1 and 8.0 - it reads as if all notifications except texts and phone calls *should* be disabled whilst you're driving, and additionally, the option to disable texts and phone calls, with both versions.